# How to install php5.6-soap extension with php5.6 version on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: soap, ubuntu-16.04, php-5.6

We have Ubuntu 16.04. server with php5.6 version, and one of our application need php5.6-soap but we can not get  a way to instal the php5.6-soap extension. When we try to install the extension the error showing:

```
Unable to locate package php5.6-soap
```

we have tried to add

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

but error "Unable to locate package php5.6-soap" keep showing.
We have also tried to

```
apt install php-soap
```

but the instalation want to install php7-soap extension.

Is this extension no longer available?
Is there a way to download the php5.6-soap source and install this extension directly from the source?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below command.

```
apt install php56-soap
```

Comment: we have tried this  apt install php56-soap to, but get same error